# How to use Single WCF Proxy in PRISM for all modules (projects)?

Tags: wpf, wcf, prism

I am developing a WPF LOB Application having several modules like Sales, Inventory, Purchase etc. I am using WCF to get data from DB. Since creation of WCG proxy is a costly affair,  I want to create a single WCF Proxy to use in all the modules. What is the best way to achieve this? Thanks in anticipation of your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

Create `IWCFService` and import it into your ViewModels. Just make sure you create it as singleton (MEF exports like this by default).

Your infrastructure project or even your shell project can hold implementation of this interface and it will be available throughout application.